# How to symbolically write "there exists at most"

Tags: notation, quantifiers

For example, an injective function can be defined as

$\forall y \in Y$ **there exists at most one** $x \, : \, \forall f(x) = y$

How could I represent the bold part of the above expression? For "there exists at least one" we have $\exists$, for "there exists a unique" we have $\exists!$. Is there a symbolic notation for "...at most one"? The classic definition of injective, i.e., $\forall \, a,b\in X, \, f(a) = f(b) \rightarrow a = b$ seems to side-step this, though.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if here was a symbol for the concept "at most one", I've never seen it.

Comment: Maybe expressible in a non-conventional logic system such as modal logic. To have a short idea of a certain number of logic systems, have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionist_logic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you will be using it repeatedly, you could invent a notation...
$$
\forall y \in Y\;\exists^{\le 1} x 
$$
Of course you will have to define it, say like this
$$
\exists^{\le 1} x\;\;\Phi(x)\qquad\text{means}\qquad
\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \big(\Phi(x_1) \wedge \Phi(x_2) \longrightarrow x_1=x_2\big)
$$

Comment: This is a very good idea...! A subscript seems to be clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of such a symbol, but if you really want to you can write $\exists !\, x \lor \nexists\, x, \,\dots $

However, this is not easily readable and I would not advise its use at all.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, an injective function can be defined as
>
> $\forall y {\in} Y$ **there exists at most one** $x : \, f(x) = y$
>
> How could I represent the bold part of the above expression? For
> "there exists at least one" we have $\exists$, for "there exists a
> unique" we have $\exists!$. Is there a symbolic notation for "...at
> most one"? The classic definition of injective, i.e., $\forall \,
> > {a,b}\in X, \, f(a) = f(b) \rightarrow a = b$ seems to side-step this,
> though.

If you accept a string of symbols in lieu, then how about:

$$\forall y{\in}Y  \; \exists p\;\forall x{\in}X\:\Big(f(x)=y \implies p=x\Big).       $$

Comment: This is incorrect. You are defining unique existence.

Comment: @SimonEatwell Nope: "exactly one" would instead be $\exists p\,\forall x\:\big(Px\leftrightarrow p{=}x\big).$

Comment: You are right. How stupid of me!

Comment: @SimonEatwell You weren't being stupid. I've just edited the answer for clarity.